# docker buildx failing with Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ecr

I have a docker image building through a circle.ci pipeline, it's pulling an ECR image from AWS and hosted on EB/EC2 and its failing to build continuously with this error:

```
#5 0.329 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [147 kB]
#5 0.339 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
#5 0.339 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
#5 0.401 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
#5 0.548 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [27.7 kB]
#5 1.597 Fetched 9179 kB in 1s (7185 kB/s)
#5 1.597 Reading package lists...
#5 2.165 E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
#5 2.165 E: Sub-process returned an error code
#5 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update]: exit code: 100
------
 > [dev 2/7] RUN apt-get update:
------
error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update]: exit code: 100
```

My Docker file

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as dev
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Custom cache invalidation
ARG CACHEBUST=1
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y pipenv default-libmysqlclient-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev

COPY Pipfile* ./
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --dev

ENV APP_DIR=/app/withinhealth
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}


FROM dev as prod
COPY . ./
```

Comment: related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76514283/aptpost-invoke-failing-on-debianbookworm-slim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the version of docker being used needs updating. I was also having this problem using an old version of docker (`20.10.6` - don't ask).

There was a Debian release a few days ago. `python:3.9-slim` derives from this new Debian version and there are some issues with running images based on this Debian version with older versions of docker (certificates and/or keys, updated version of glibc perhaps).

Minimal steps to reproduce (with docker version `20.10.6`):

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.9-slim bash
root@f350ecdf0140:/# apt update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [147 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [28.3 kB]
Fetched 9180 kB in 2s (5210 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Following upgrade of docker to `24.0.2`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.9-slim bash
root@6824359f6240:/# apt update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [147 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [28.3 kB]
Fetched 9180 kB in 2s (5248 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: Thanks the upgrade worked along with upgrading to `python:3.9-slim-bullseye`

Comment: As bullseye was the version of Debian before bookworm this would have been used in the `python:3.9-slim` image before it was [updated](https://github.com/docker-library/python/commit/5d908b0477c003712550c84ac4d133367b912f78) to use bookworm, so if you are using `python:3.9-slim-bullseye` I don't _think_ you would need to upgrade docker.

Comment: My docker version is exactly 24.0.2, however reproducing from gitlab runner shell fails. yet the runner itself still gets this error when trying to execute via pipeline deployment..

Comment: Do the runner shell and pipeline use the same environment (I assume not, or you'd get the same result in both cases)? Are your pipeline runners docker based, if so what is the base image, if not what is the operating system/version of the runner?