# APT:Post-Invoke failing on debian:bookworm-slim

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, debian, apt

I have a Jenkins pipeline that uses a `docker-dind:20`. In that process I do:

```
FROM ruby:3.2-slim-bookworm
apt-get update
```

When I try to build the image locally (MacOS ventura) with my `docker` client it succeeds.

On `Jenkins` it fails with

```
Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

`Jenkins` uses an agent with 2 containers, one `docker-dind:20` and another using `google/cloud-sdk:403.0.0`.

The build of course is executed in the `docker-dind:20`

Amy ideas what might be the root cause and why it succeeds on my Mac?

Comment: This answer may (or may not) be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/76514507/3112752.